# How can I avoid a closed result set exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, resultset

I am using below code

```
public List<Test> getData(String sectionNumber) {
    String query = "SELECT  FROM test WHERE section_number = ?";

    log.info("Executing method {}", "getData");
    log.info("fetching details for {}", query);

    return jdbcTemplate.query(query, new Object[] { sectionNumber }, new RowMapper<Test>() {

        public Test mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Test cal = new Test();
            cal.setAsseType(rs.getString("INV_SEQ_ID"));
            return cal;
        }
    });

}
```

It's working fine if result set size is small, but if size is big, I get an exception as result set closed.

I'm not able to identify the issue from above.

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace and specify which DBMS (and its version), and JDBC driver (and its version) you're using.

Comment: It could be query timeout or data quantity policy.